# ReactJS. Pages are not working after being refreshed and deployed with React Router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have used npm run build to create a folder with files that I uploaded to my hosting to public folder. All was working fine, the homepage, links, everything until I clicked on the refresh button. It suddenly shows 404 error.

I also can not access i.e mywebsite.com/about from search bar, however, if I go to the main page mywebsite.com and click on a link to about then all is working fine as long as I don't click refresh button.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it? I have really no clue.

Here is my code from App.js

```
<>
     <div className='wrapper '>
        <Router>
           <Navbar onClick={newButton} isClose={isClose} />
           <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Header />} />
              <Route
                 path='/portfolio'
                 element={
                    <Portfolio onClick={newButton} isClose={isClose} />
                 }
              />
              <Route
                 path='/about'
                 element={<About onClick={newButton} isClose={isClose} />}
              />
              <Route path='/' element={<Header />} />
              <Route
                 path='/skills'
                 element={<Skills onClick={newButton} isClose={isClose} />}
              />
           </Routes>
        </Router>
     </div>
  </>
```

Comment: Check console. It should show some error regarding this.

Comment: Are you using BrowserRouter and Routes as in this example? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-basepath-forked-j7mrfi?file=/src/App.js:377-383

Comment: Yes, I use it exactly like in your example. In my code the BrowserRouter is just called Router, this is how I imported it. 

There is nothing wrong in the console. Everything is working until I upload the files on the server, is there a chance that is something to do with .htaccess file?

Comment: I don't think it's related to react-router. It sounds like a classic history API issue. You have to configure your server properly. Where did you deploy your website?

Comment: Please give the [create react app - deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs a good read over and find the section applicable to your server and how you are deploying your app. Each server environment will have its own setup/configuration. The server needs to be configured to route all page requests to your root index.html file so the app load and handles routing to the correct page in app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create _redirects file in the public folder and put the following code

/* /index.html 200

build files again npm run build then host your app. I hope it will work.