# Email password reset link does not work with deployed React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passwords

I recently finished a project in React, only the client side was developed, I used a ready-made API. One of the features is password reset, which in the development environment was working perfectly, but after deploying to the platform (I think the platform is irrelevant as the same problem occurred on both Vercel and Netlify).

The problem is that the link to reset the password is sent to the user's email, but when clicked, the reset page is not found, I need help, both to fix the bug and to find out the cause in future projects.

Here is the repository, feel free to suggest changes and ask for more details, thanks: (https://github.com/hermesonbastos/Dogs-React)

[image]

[image]

api.jsx

```
export const API_URL = "https://dogsapi.origamid.dev/json";

export function PASSWORD_LOST(body) {
  return {
    url: API_URL + "/api/password/lost",
    options: {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    },
  };
}

export function PASSWORD_RESET(body) {
  return {
    url: API_URL + "/api/password/reset",
    options: {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    },
  };
}
```

Login.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
import LoginCreate from "./LoginCreate";
import LoginPasswordLost from "./LoginPasswordLost";
import LoginPasswordReset from "./LoginPasswordReset";
import { UserContext } from "../../UserContext";
import styles from "./Login.module.css";
import NotFound from "../NotFound";

const Login = () => {
  const { login } = React.useContext(UserContext);

  if (login === true) return <Navigate to="/conta" />;
  return (
    <section className={styles.login}>
      <div className={styles.forms}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginForm />} />
          <Route path="criar" element={<LoginCreate />} />
          <Route path="perdeu" element={<LoginPasswordLost />} />
          <Route path="resetar" element={<LoginPasswordReset />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

LoginPasswordReset.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "../Forms/Input";
import Button from "../Forms/Button";
import useForm from "../../Hooks/useForm";
import { PASSWORD_RESET } from "../../api";
import useFetch from "../../Hooks/useFetch";
import Error from "../Helper/Error";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Head from "../Helper/Head";

const LoginPasswordReset = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = React.useState("");
  const [login, setLogin] = React.useState("");
  const password = useForm();
  const { error, loading, request } = useFetch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const key = params.get("key");
    const login = params.get("login");
    if (key) setKey(key);
    if (login) setLogin(login);
  }, []);

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (password.validate()) {
      const { url, options } = PASSWORD_RESET({
        login,
        key,
        password: password.value,
      });
      const { response } = await request(url, options);
      if (response.ok) navigate("/login");
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="animeLeft">
      <Head title="Resete a senha" />
      <h1 className="title">Resete a Senha</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          label="Nova Senha"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          {...password}
        />
        {loading ? (
          <Button disabled>Resetando...</Button>
        ) : (
          <Button>Resetar</Button>
        )}
      </form>
      <Error error={error} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default LoginPasswordReset;
```

Comment: Where have you defined `API_URL`?

Comment: Yes, i will edit the question, thanks, but i believe that the problem is not that.

Comment: What url is your link from email?

Comment: https://dogsapi.origamid.dev/json/api/password/lost returned a 404. Are you sure you are sending the request to the correct endpoint?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct URL, as I said before, the exact same code is working on localhost. This URL `dogsapi.origamid.dev/json/api/password/lost` requires a JSON with username or email used for login by the user, to finally send the password reset link via the user's email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, to solve it had to create a file called “_redirects”, with content:

/* /index.html 200

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71707938/reactjs-pages-are-not-working-after-being-refreshed-and-deployed-with-react-rou)

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion resolved the application redirection

Answer (score 1):

As [Gustavo Henrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17806531/gustavo-henrique) already mentioned for Netlify, I want to add the solution for the latter on Vercel. Create a **vercel.json** file at root directory with the content:

```
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the [doc link](https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/redirects).